# What is the most efficient way of replacing duplicate elements in a list B with unique elements from another list(list A) in Qt or C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two sorted lists of integers, list A and list B with n and m elements respectively, where n can be less than, or equal to, m. The lists are sorted in ascending order.

List B contains duplicate elements, but the total number of "different" elements in list B is equal to m, the number of elements in list A.

What is an efficient way to replace the elements from list B, with those from list A, such that list B will also contain duplicate elements of list A

Example :

```
List A = {2,3,6,12};
List B = {3,3,3,3,4,4,4,7,7,7,7,10,10,10}
```

After replacement:

```
List B' = {2,2,2,2,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,12,12,12}
```

This is what I currently have, C++(Qt creator)

```
void replace(QList<int> &A, QList<int> &B)
{
    if(B.isEmpty()|| A.isEmpty())
        return;

    int i = 0;      
    int curr;       //the current duplicate being replaced from B

    for(int j: A)
    {
        curr = B[i];        //store the current duplicate, for comparison
        for(; i < B.length(); i++){
            //iterate through B, replacing elements equal to the current
            //duplicate, with the current replacement element
            if( curr == B.at(i)){
                B[i] = j;
            }
            else
            break;      //if no longer equal,exit and move to next
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try posting your solution, SO is not a code-service website

Comment: Since i'm looking for a different way of doing it, I'm trying not to 'muddy the waters' with the algorithm I already have. I hope you understand.

Comment: Ok, then post your code and try to explain it. It will help you more than you think

Comment: Ok, let me edit and post what I have.

Comment: @Neb I've added my code:)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a nested loop. This function iterates over the element of B. When it checks that the element of B is changed, then  it takes the next element of A and insert it into the vector B. As a consequence it has a linear complexity.

```
int posA{0};
int currentB = B[0];
int currentA = A[posA];

for (int i = 0; i < B.length(); i++)
{
     if (B[i] != currentB)
     {
       posA++;
       currentB = B[i];
       currentA = A[posA];
     }
     B[i] = currentA;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try writing a nested for loop in another for loop. The first loop will run every element of the array, and the second one will do the same while comparing each element with all the others, and then I will write an if else statement. If two elements have the same value, and they are not the same element. Then call another function and replace that element with one of the second array. 
If you need help let me know I will try writing the code.